# Boolean in geonodes leaving behind faces that cover the created hole

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

The boolean difference is working, as you can see the new geometry in the wireframe mode.  But it is leaving a separate face behind that covers the hole.

[image: Previewed Geometry]
[image: Wireframe showing internal geometry]
[image: Geonodes setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone who may come across this post as it was straightforward.  I used a "delete geometry" node set to "face" and "all" and used the "intersecting edges" output from the "Mesh Boolean" node as the selection for the "Delete Geometry" node.